# Unreal Engine 4.27.2 is not creating C++ project

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

The project could not be compiled. Would you like to open it in Visual Studio Code?

```
Running Mono...

Found mono via known Mono.framework path
Running system mono/msbuild, version: Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.182 (2020-02/6051b710727 Tue Jun 14 15:01:21 EDT 2022)
/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.27/Engine /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.27/Engine/Binaries/Mac
Creating makefile for MyProject5Editor (no existing makefile)
@progress push 5%
Parsing headers for MyProject5Editor
  Running UnrealHeaderTool "/Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject5/MyProject5.uproject" "/Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject5/Intermediate/Build/Mac/x86_64/MyProject5Editor/Development/MyProject5Editor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -abslog="/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/Epic/UnrealBuildTool/Log_UHT.txt" -installed
2022-07-15 02:15:18.637 UnrealHeaderTool[72641:1404893] [UE4] Looking for binary: ../../../Engine/Programs/UnrealHeaderTool/Config/BinaryConfig.ini
LogInit: Display: Loading text-based GConfig....
Reflection code generated for MyProject5Editor in 5.5839518 seconds
@progress pop
Building MyProject5Editor...
Performing 7 actions (5 in parallel)
[1/7] Compile SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.h
In file included from /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject5/Intermediate/Build/Mac/x86_64/MyProject5Editor/Development/Engine/SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.h:284:
In file included from /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.27/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Public/EngineSharedPCH.h:572:
/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.27/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Classes/Materials/Material.h:1279:26: error: variable 'LayerNames' set but not used [-Werror,-Wunused-but-set-variable]
                                const TArray<FText>* LayerNames = &LayersExpression->GetLayerNames();
                                                     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: _"Would you like to open it in Visual Studio Code?"_ Open what??

Comment: The error/warning seems clear enough, is there something stopping you fixing it? Or is your question about something else?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could just pass the actual error which is

```
error: variable 'LayerNames' set but not used [-Werror,-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

and google would quickly show you this:
https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/layernames-error-bricking-my-mac-projects/508040

According to this post:

> Downloading and replacing Xcode 13.3 with Xcode 13.2.1 fixes the issue
> https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.2.1/Xcode_13.2.1.xip